# Java-new instance cannot get static method

Tags: java, static, apache-commons

I can compile

```
DigestUtils digestUtils = new DigestUtils();
String sign = digestUtils.shaHex(signStr);
```

before, but recently, the compiler would call shaHex deprecated.

However, if I changed to call static method directly, it's ok for compiler.

```
String sign = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(signStr);
```

Does anyone know the reason??

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DigestUtils class -- is this part of core Java? I cannot find it in the Java 10 API.  And if not, what is the source of this class? Does it have an API? And if so, what does the API state about these methods?

Comment: OK it appears to be part of Apache Commons and the [API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) states that one method is deprecated and to use the other. That's the reason -- because the designers desired to change it. As to why, I don't see that in the API.

Comment: I've added the Apache Commons tag to your question, but in the future, you'll want to do this, to add relevant information. Also in the future, search the API first when asking these types of questions. A Google search will find it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is described in this doc: [DigestUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html)
[image]